# I am unable to automate slider in selenium

Tags: selenium

http://automationpractice.com

How to automate slider? I have tried with clickandhold, movetoelement by offset.

My problem is: the script stops executing in draganddrop line of my code, when I manually point the mouse over the element it performs draganddrop action

```
String driverPath;

driverPath = "D:/software wishes/jdk and jre/geckodriver-v0.16.1-win64/";
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", driverPath+"geckodriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 80);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@class='sf-with-ul' and text()='Women']")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@class='sf-with-ul' and text()='Women']")));

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='sf-with-ul' and text()='Women']"));
action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("T-shirts")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText("T-shirts")));

WebElement tops = driver.findElement(By.linkText("T-shirts"));
action.moveToElement(tops);
action.click().build().perform(); 

By locator = By.cssSelector(".ui-slider-handle.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all.ui-state-hover");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));

WebElement sliderRight = driver.findElement(locator);
action.dragAndDropBy(sliderRight,-40,0).build().perform();
```

Comment: I had a similar issue with `dragAndDropBy` not performing.

I use this line of code and it works: 
`(new Actions(driver)).clickAndHold(elementFrom).moveToElement(elementTo).moveByOffset(1, 0).release().perform()`